Hay this is specific about which definition to use for the STFT
It's about if the phase of the DTFT or DFT of each frame should be adjusted to remain coherent between adjacent frames or not (which means that one frame will have a linear phase term, proportional to the hop compared to its neighbor).
Can some of you weigh in here?  It's about changing this answer or not.  Check out the Wikipedia definition and what you can find in the lit (that's not behind a paywall).  Like here.
What should I do to the answer, in your opinion?  Phase adjustment to make phase-coherent adjacent frames or not?

I'm not qualified to answer this, I went on an interesting exploration trying to find and answer, which is yes; it should (must) be phase coherent, depends on what result you want (good versus bad). See https://www.dsprelated.com/freebooks/sasp/Short_Time_Fourier_Transform.html https://blogs.zynaptiq.com/bernsee/pitch-shifting-using-the-ft/ - when you inverse to convert back of pitch shift it will be phasey (even chipmunky) if not corrected. I only made this partially helpful comment because it looks like you've waited too long for an answer; one you are better qualified to write than me.

Well, thank you.  That definition is consistent with my answer as it is now.  I did end up changing it.

You're welcome, I don't see any changes though.

Need to look at the revision history.  Compare the dates with this post to DSP meta.
